# Calculating Kolmogorov Smirnov stats for multiple variables

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R coding world.
I want to calculate KS stat for multiple variables whereby the variables are in excel.
I have been trying to loop the calculation from one variable to another and to store the KS results in data frame.
I have no issue to calculate the KS stat for single variable e.g. `FINALGRADE`.
Below is the data with multiple variables I have e.g. tmp.

QUESTION: How can I get the KS r-codes to calculate from one variable to another variable and store the variables KS results in data frame?

The KS stats is the difference between score of defaulted customers and non-defaulted customers.

```
    ID  Default FINALGRADE  FINALSCORE  PREOVERRIDESCORE    SUBJECTIVESCORE FINANCIALSCORE
    10009011    0   8   67.65854557 67.65854557 68.36424313 60.2136826
    10020003    0   7   72.18560889 72.18560889 70.97483009 64.35831722
    10020003    0   6   77.23072833 77.23072833 69.87370952 71.53180821
    10021201    0   14  40.21338437 40.21338437 58.06865599 40.54564338
    10021201    0   8   68.79085151 68.79085151 72.59254723 58.91827403
    10022730    0   4   84.47284986 84.47284986 78.03588557 77.85944161
    10022731    0   5   78.28775535 78.28775535 82.07915713 64.45948626
    10025555    0   15  7.907947702 7.907947702 57.95049201 4.075100629
    10025555    0   13  1.75            47.15981982 72.56744037 39.16338519
    10025763    0   15  66.39063143 66.39063143 79.10054245 52.66288527
    10029315    1   14  40.36515221 40.36515221 57.9586825  40.78027744
    10030999    0   17  25.78498104 25.78498104 84.37428799 16.36896422
    10030999    0   13  47.90043592 47.90043592 78.97405559 36.28646008
    10033303    0   10  58.50724135 58.50724135 74.95635833 47.05689989
    10033938    0   15  32.79988473 37.79988473 45.90931406 43.84648718
    10039393    1   8   67.31395864 67.31395864 74.81030489 55.26979858
    10039780    0   9   64.94318991 69.94318991 69.44595762 62.06825469
    10040777    0   13  44.93908421 44.93908421 81.83346015 32.38398138
    10041213    0   15  33.05768436 33.05768436 73.75578861 27.6882957
    10041213    0   15  35.39463308 35.39463308 73.75578861 28.95912606
    10045566    1   8   70.60067856 70.60067856 70.87753432 61.88535995
    10045566    0   10  58.50956434 58.50956434 70.87753432 49.89960356
    10045692    0   12  50.52222802 50.52222802 50.91083454 52.10279587
    10045692    0   10  59.17371704 59.17371704 57.49697166 57.37504351
    10046390    1   10  60.47796914 60.47796914 67.94551866 52.29460738
    10047830    0   12  51.46066369 51.46066369 79.14482394 39.16019407
    10048824    0   13  50.86887099 50.86887099 65.6366083  46.18752406
    10048824    0   12  49.82958553 49.82958553 60.56566557 47.97788939
    10050504    0   8   67.47839481 67.47839481 72.53163793 58.4371572
    10050504    0   7   73.7608865  73.7608865  69.49809267 67.26984194
```

```
# calculate KS
> n_S <- length(tmp$FINALGRADE)

> d <- sum(tmp$Default)

> g <- sum(tmp$Default==0)

> x_S <- NULL

> y_S <- NULL

> z_S <- NULL

>defaultcnt_s <- 0

> goodcnt_s <- 0

> ordereddata <-tmp[order(tmp$FINALGRADE),]

> default <-  ifelse((ordereddata$Default == 0), 0, 1)

> good <- ifelse((ordereddata$Default == 0), 1, 0)

> for (i in 1:n_S)

> {x_S[i] = i/n_S

> defaultcnt_s <- defaultcnt_s + default[i]

> goodcnt_s <- goodcnt_s + good[i]

> y_S[i] <- defaultcnt_s/d

> z_S[i] <- goodcnt_s/g

> }

> K_S <- abs(y_S[which.max(abs(y_S-z_S))]-z_S[which.max(abs(y_S-z_S))])

> ks.test(y_S,z_S,alternative = c('two.sided','less','greater'))
```

```
    Variable    FINALGRADE  FINALSCORE  PREOVERRIDESCORE    SUBJECTIVESCORE FINANCIALSCORE  
    KS          …           …           …                   …           …
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, in base R. (Data at the end.)

You want to do pair-wise comparisons/tests. A function `expand.grid` will give you every pairwise combination given 2 or more vectors. (It works with a single vector, but that's not as interesting.)

```r
cn <- colnames(x)[-(1:2)] # don't need ID, Default
eg <- expand.grid(x=cn, y=cn, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
nrow(eg)
# [1] 25
head(eg)
#                  x          y
# 1       FINALGRADE FINALGRADE
# 2       FINALSCORE FINALGRADE
# 3 PREOVERRIDESCORE FINALGRADE
# 4  SUBJECTIVESCORE FINALGRADE
# 5   FINANCIALSCORE FINALGRADE
# 6       FINALGRADE FINALSCORE
```

We can remove testing "column 1 against 1". We can also reduce testing "1 against 2" *and* "2 against 1" (same results), so we'll remove those duplicates as well (by sorting row-wise and removing duplicates).

```r
eg <- eg[ eg$x != eg$y, ]
eg$x1 <- ifelse(eg$x < eg$y, eg$x, eg$y)
eg$y <- ifelse(eg$x < eg$y, eg$y, eg$x)
eg$x <- eg$x1
eg$x1 <- NULL # remove the added column
eg <- eg[ !duplicated(eg), ]
head(eg)
#            x                y
# 2 FINALGRADE       FINALSCORE
# 3 FINALGRADE PREOVERRIDESCORE
# 4 FINALGRADE  SUBJECTIVESCORE
# 5 FINALGRADE   FINANCIALSCORE
# 8 FINALSCORE PREOVERRIDESCORE
# 9 FINALSCORE  SUBJECTIVESCORE
nrow(eg)
# [1] 10
```

Now we can do the tests.

```r
results <- Map(function(i1, i2) ks.test(x[,i1], x[,i2]),
               eg$x, eg$y)
# Warning in ks.test(x[, i1], x[, i2]) :
#   cannot compute exact p-value with ties
### repeated total of eight times ... it's a problem with the data

results[[1]]
#   Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
# data:  x[, i1] and x[, i2]
# D = 0.93333, p-value = 8.943e-12
# alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

We now have all 10 tests in a single named list. Unfortunately, the names are not perfectly helpful, as they currently only include the first variable, not both.

```r
names(results)
#  [1] "FINALGRADE"       "FINALGRADE"       "FINALGRADE"       "FINALGRADE"      
#  [5] "FINALSCORE"       "FINALSCORE"       "FINALSCORE"       "PREOVERRIDESCORE"
#  [9] "FINANCIALSCORE"   "FINANCIALSCORE"
```

It's easy enough to fix that.

```r
names(results) <- paste(eg$x, eg$y, sep = "_")
str(results[1:2])
# List of 2
#  $ FINALGRADE_FINALSCORE      :List of 5
#   ..$ statistic  : Named num 0.933
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "D"
#   ..$ p.value    : num 8.94e-12
#   ..$ alternative: chr "two-sided"
#   ..$ method     : chr "Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test"
#   ..$ data.name  : chr "x[, i1] and x[, i2]"
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
#  $ FINALGRADE_PREOVERRIDESCORE:List of 5
#   ..$ statistic  : Named num 0.967
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "D"
#   ..$ p.value    : num 1.34e-12
#   ..$ alternative: chr "two-sided"
#   ..$ method     : chr "Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test"
#   ..$ data.name  : chr "x[, i1] and x[, i2]"
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

You might want *just* the `p.value` (or one other statistic) from each test. This can easily be accomplished with `lapply` (returns a `list`) or `sapply` (often returns a vector):

```r
sapply(results, `[[`, "p.value")
#            FINALGRADE_FINALSCORE      FINALGRADE_PREOVERRIDESCORE 
#                     8.942624e-12                     1.337597e-12 
#       FINALGRADE_SUBJECTIVESCORE        FINALGRADE_FINANCIALSCORE 
#                     1.871836e-13                     8.942624e-12 
#      FINALSCORE_PREOVERRIDESCORE       FINALSCORE_SUBJECTIVESCORE 
#                     9.999999e-01                     1.106169e-03 
#        FINALSCORE_FINANCIALSCORE PREOVERRIDESCORE_SUBJECTIVESCORE 
#                     1.350035e-01                     2.908301e-03 
#  FINANCIALSCORE_PREOVERRIDESCORE   FINANCIALSCORE_SUBJECTIVESCORE 
#                     1.350035e-01                     3.239194e-06
```

Or, instead of dealing with individual vectors and such, you could add it to the `eg` frame:

```r
head(eg)
#            x                y      p.value
# 2 FINALGRADE       FINALSCORE 8.942624e-12
# 3 FINALGRADE PREOVERRIDESCORE 1.337597e-12
# 4 FINALGRADE  SUBJECTIVESCORE 1.871836e-13
# 5 FINALGRADE   FINANCIALSCORE 8.942624e-12
# 8 FINALSCORE PREOVERRIDESCORE 9.999999e-01
# 9 FINALSCORE  SUBJECTIVESCORE 1.106169e-03
```

If you want all of them, you can easily do that, too:

```r
cbind(eg, sapply(c("statistic", "p.value", "alternative"),
                 function(nm) sapply(results, `[[`, nm),
                 simplify = FALSE),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#                   x                y      p.value  statistic      p.value alternative
# 2        FINALGRADE       FINALSCORE 8.942624e-12 0.93333333 8.942624e-12   two-sided
# 3        FINALGRADE PREOVERRIDESCORE 1.337597e-12 0.96666667 1.337597e-12   two-sided
# 4        FINALGRADE  SUBJECTIVESCORE 1.871836e-13 1.00000000 1.871836e-13   two-sided
# 5        FINALGRADE   FINANCIALSCORE 8.942624e-12 0.93333333 8.942624e-12   two-sided
# 8        FINALSCORE PREOVERRIDESCORE 9.999999e-01 0.06666667 9.999999e-01   two-sided
# 9        FINALSCORE  SUBJECTIVESCORE 1.106169e-03 0.50000000 1.106169e-03   two-sided
# 10       FINALSCORE   FINANCIALSCORE 1.350035e-01 0.30000000 1.350035e-01   two-sided
# 14 PREOVERRIDESCORE  SUBJECTIVESCORE 2.908301e-03 0.46666667 2.908301e-03   two-sided
# 15   FINANCIALSCORE PREOVERRIDESCORE 1.350035e-01 0.30000000 1.350035e-01   two-sided
# 20   FINANCIALSCORE  SUBJECTIVESCORE 3.239194e-06 0.66666667 3.239194e-06   two-sided
```

---

Data:

```r
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
ID  Default FINALGRADE  FINALSCORE  PREOVERRIDESCORE    SUBJECTIVESCORE FINANCIALSCORE
10009011    0   8   67.65854557 67.65854557 68.36424313 60.2136826
10020003    0   7   72.18560889 72.18560889 70.97483009 64.35831722
10020003    0   6   77.23072833 77.23072833 69.87370952 71.53180821
10021201    0   14  40.21338437 40.21338437 58.06865599 40.54564338
10021201    0   8   68.79085151 68.79085151 72.59254723 58.91827403
10022730    0   4   84.47284986 84.47284986 78.03588557 77.85944161
10022731    0   5   78.28775535 78.28775535 82.07915713 64.45948626
10025555    0   15  7.907947702 7.907947702 57.95049201 4.075100629
10025555    0   13  1.75            47.15981982 72.56744037 39.16338519
10025763    0   15  66.39063143 66.39063143 79.10054245 52.66288527
10029315    1   14  40.36515221 40.36515221 57.9586825  40.78027744
10030999    0   17  25.78498104 25.78498104 84.37428799 16.36896422
10030999    0   13  47.90043592 47.90043592 78.97405559 36.28646008
10033303    0   10  58.50724135 58.50724135 74.95635833 47.05689989
10033938    0   15  32.79988473 37.79988473 45.90931406 43.84648718
10039393    1   8   67.31395864 67.31395864 74.81030489 55.26979858
10039780    0   9   64.94318991 69.94318991 69.44595762 62.06825469
10040777    0   13  44.93908421 44.93908421 81.83346015 32.38398138
10041213    0   15  33.05768436 33.05768436 73.75578861 27.6882957
10041213    0   15  35.39463308 35.39463308 73.75578861 28.95912606
10045566    1   8   70.60067856 70.60067856 70.87753432 61.88535995
10045566    0   10  58.50956434 58.50956434 70.87753432 49.89960356
10045692    0   12  50.52222802 50.52222802 50.91083454 52.10279587
10045692    0   10  59.17371704 59.17371704 57.49697166 57.37504351
10046390    1   10  60.47796914 60.47796914 67.94551866 52.29460738
10047830    0   12  51.46066369 51.46066369 79.14482394 39.16019407
10048824    0   13  50.86887099 50.86887099 65.6366083  46.18752406
10048824    0   12  49.82958553 49.82958553 60.56566557 47.97788939
10050504    0   8   67.47839481 67.47839481 72.53163793 58.4371572
10050504    0   7   73.7608865  73.7608865  69.49809267 67.26984194')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
results <- outer( 
  1:ncol(df), 1:ncol(df), 
  Vectorize(
    function (i,j) ks.test(df[,i], df[,j], alternative = c('two.sided'))$p.value
  ) 
)
#Because the output is matrix we can convert it to data.frame and set the names of the columns 
results <- as.data.frame(results)
names(results) <- names(df)
```

Result:

```
                          ID      Default   FINALGRADE
ID               1.000000e+00 1.871836e-13 1.871836e-13
Default          1.871836e-13 1.000000e+00 1.871836e-13
FINALGRADE       1.871836e-13 1.871836e-13 1.000000e+00
FINALSCORE       1.871836e-13 1.871836e-13 8.942624e-12
PREOVERRIDESCORE 1.871836e-13 1.871836e-13 1.337597e-12
SUBJECTIVESCORE  1.871836e-13 1.871836e-13 1.871836e-13
FINANCIALSCORE   1.871836e-13 1.871836e-13 8.942624e-12
                   FINALSCORE PREOVERRIDESCORE SUBJECTIVESCORE
ID               1.871836e-13     1.871836e-13    1.871836e-13
Default          1.871836e-13     1.871836e-13    1.871836e-13
FINALGRADE       8.942624e-12     1.337597e-12    1.871836e-13
FINALSCORE       1.000000e+00     9.999999e-01    1.106169e-03
PREOVERRIDESCORE 9.999999e-01     1.000000e+00    2.908301e-03
SUBJECTIVESCORE  1.106169e-03     2.908301e-03    1.000000e+00
FINANCIALSCORE   1.350035e-01     1.350035e-01    3.239194e-06
                 FINANCIALSCORE
ID                 1.871836e-13
Default            1.871836e-13
FINALGRADE         8.942624e-12
FINALSCORE         1.350035e-01
PREOVERRIDESCORE   1.350035e-01
SUBJECTIVESCORE    3.239194e-06
```

Answer (score 0):

Truly appreciate reply from @r2evans and @DJV.

Appreciate if you can further help me on my problem.

Maybe I didn't explain my KS calculation clearly. actually, I require to calculate the KS of max score plot / score difference between default (default = 1) and good (default = 0).

That's why I have this part of the codes to see the distribution good and default. So basically I calculate the KS to the see the difference between FINALGRADE (default = 1) vs. FINALGRADE (default = 0).

> y_S[i] <- defaultcnt_s/d
>
> z_S[i] <- goodcnt_s/g
>
> K_S <- abs(y_S[which.max(abs(y_S-z_S))]-z_S[which.max(abs(y_S-z_S))])

Theoretical and simple illustration of FINALGRADE KS which is the max difference of good vs. bad is attached:

[FINALGRADE KS which is the max difference of good vs. bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEISZ.jpg)

Comment: M.X.Z, a couple of things: (1) this is not an answer, it is feedback to some other answers; as such, please [edit your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55553311/edit) and place the relevant components there. Once you've done that, please delete this "answer". (2) Since it was not a comment in my answer (or a *comment* elsewhere that pinged me personally), I did not know it was here. I suspect DJV has not seen it either, but I don't know for certain.